# what is the difference between _exit function and return statement in linux

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int g_a = 1;

int main(void){
    int l_b = 1;
    pid_t p;
    if((p = vfork()) < 0){
            perror("vfork");
            return -1;
    }else if(p == 0){
            g_a++;
            l_b++;
            _exit(0);   //use the system call _exit
    }
    printf("ppid = %d,pid = %d,g_a = %d,l_b = %d\n", getppid(), getpid(), g_a, l_b);
    return 0;
}
```

the result as follow:
    ppid = 21297,pid = 21553,g_a = 2,l_b = 2

but when i replace the _exit(0); with return 0;, the result became:

ppid = 21297,pid = 21563,g_a = 2,l_b = -1216841009

Segmentation fault

there is a segmentation faut，what is the difference between _exit and return??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning from `main` is equivalent to calling [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit), which does a bunch of cleanup operations (such as flushing open `FILE` objects and running [`atexit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) procedures) and then calls [`_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit), which is the system call that actually terminates a process.  So when you call `_exit` directly, you skip all of those cleanup operations.

You are using [`vfork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/vfork).  It is incorrect (formally, it "provokes undefined behavior") to do *anything* on the child side of a `vfork` except call `_exit` or [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).  Returning from `main` counts as doing something else (namely, calling `exit`).  It is not at all surprising, therefore, that your program crashes.

**EDIT:** As far as the relevant specifications are concerned, modifying the variables `g_a` and `l_b` on the child side of the `vfork` is *also* forbidden, in the same dire terms ("undefined behavior" in the strong sense, i.e. "allowed to cause your program to crash").  *However,* in all extant implementations I am aware of, catastrophe only strikes if the child does anything to cause memory (including stack frames) to be allocated or deallocated.  Modifying variables that were allocated by the parent, but visible to the child (whether local or global) is unpredictable in a much more bounded manner:

1. If `vfork` is just another name for `fork`, nothing the child does will be visible in the parent;
2. But if `vfork` has its special behavior of delaying allocation of the new address space until `execve`, then modifications by the child *to variables resident in memory* will be visible in the parent after the parent resumes execution.  (Variables resident in registers may or may not get reset when the kernel restores the parent's execution context, depending on how full a context switch that does.)

And, if you know your OS is type 2, you can get away with using this to your advantage, e.g. to pass `errno` back to the parent after `execve` fails, which is significantly harder with plain `fork` (because the exit status is too narrow).  It is, however, something you are getting away with rather than something you are entitled to do; in particular it is a source of future portability headaches.